# How to set jasmine for karma e2e for testing angular app?

Tags: testing, angularjs, jasmine, yeoman, karma-runner

I try to create e2e tests with karma and jasmine with yeoman. In my `karma-e2e.conf.js` I add jasmine:

```
files = [
   JASMINE,
   JASMINE_ADAPTER,
   ANGULAR_SCENARIO,
   ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER,
   'test/e2e/**/*.js'
];
```

A need async testing so I need to use `runs`, `waits`, `waitsFor` (https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Asynchronous-specs)

But if I try to use it:

```
it('test', function () {
    runs(function () {
        ...
    });
});
```

Scenatio test runner returns this:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'runs' of null
    at runs (http://localhost:8080/adapter/lib/jasmine.js:562:32)
    at Object.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/base/test/e2e/eduUser.js:42:3)
    at Object.angular.scenario.SpecRunner.run   (http://localhost:8080/adapter/lib/angular-scenario.js:27057:15)
    at Object.run (http://localhost:8080/adapter/lib/angular-scenario.js:10169:18)
```

I don't know where the problem is. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Angular e2e tests with Karma don't and can't use the `JASMINE` adapter. Instead you have the `ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER` which has a similar feel to writing Jasmine tests.

All commands in the adapter's [API](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing#api) are asynchronous anyway. For example `element('#nav-items').count()` doesn't return a number, it returns a `Future` object. `Future` objects are placed in a queue and executed asynchronously as the runner progresses. To quote the [API docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing#api):

> **expect(future).{matcher}:**
>
> [...] All API statements return a `future` object, which get a value assigned after they are executed.

If you need to run your own asynchronous test code, you can extend the adapter's DSL, this is easier than it might sound. The idea is that you return your own `Future` which can be evaluated by a matcher such as `toBe()`. There are some examples on how to do this in [the e2e-tests.js Gist from Vojta](https://gist.github.com/vojtajina/1840093). Just remember to call `done(null, myRetrunValue);` when your test code is successful (`myRetrunValue` is the value evaluated by your matcher). Or `done('Your own error message');` if you want the test to fail.

**UPDATE: In response to question below.** To simulate a login, first add a function called `login` to the `dsl`:

```
angular.scenario.dsl('login', function() {
  return function(selector) {
    
    // @param {DOMWindow} appWindow The window object of the iframe (the application)
    // @param {jQuery} $document jQuery wrapped document of the application
    // @param {function(error, value)} done Callback that should be called when done
    //                                      (will basically call the next item in the queuue)
    return this.addFutureAction('Logging in', function(appWindow, $document, done) {

      // You can do normal jQuery/jqLite stuff here on $document, just call done() when your asynchronous tasks have completed
      
      // Create some kind of listener to handle when your login is complete
      $document.one('loginComplete', function(e){
        done(null, true);
      }).one('loginError', function(e){
        done('Login error', false);
      });
      
      // Simulate the button click
      var loginButton = $document.find(selector || 'button.login');
      loginButton.click();
    })
  };
});
```

And then call:

```
beforeEach( function()
{
    expect( login('button.login') ).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Comment: thanks this looks good. I need test app with login. So I want to add login into beforeEach and logout into afterEach. After login click() I have to wait for finish login process. What do you think is this good approach?

Comment: @MarekL, I've updated the answer with a code example. Hope it helps.

Comment: this answer help me, but I am still struggling with it. I create new next question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983116/how-to-create-e2e-karma-tests-for-angular-app-with-xhr-requests